# How can I associate a folder to some file descriptor?

Tags: command-line, files

We can open(I mean similar to c function open) a file with exec 33<> /tmp/ffs. So it gets associated with fd 33. How can I do this to a folder? I want to associate a folder with some fd.

Comment: Can't see what you should do with a file descriptor to a directory?

Comment: @bac0n I'll use it for openat syscall it needs s dirfd and I can open files relative to that dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be open read-only.

```
exec 33< /path/to/dir
```

Apart from some system calls, I cannot imagine any use for a directory file descriptor.

Comment: Not sure if this works, My syscall is still failing. I am using openat syscall with that fd it expects a dirfd and I can open things relative to it.

Comment: So I got it working. I am not really sure how it worked but I created two fd's then did something like   ./program fd1 >&fd2 . This opened the fd1 in my suid binary then the openat syscall worked. I am not sure how it worked but it did.